# WinForms: Binding functionality is broken when overriding GetHashCode in base class

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I've simplified my code to the following short example that reproduce the error. I'm trying to bind a value of a derived class to a control. The derived class and the binding logic are:

```
bindingSource = new BindingSource();
numericUpDown1.DataBindings.Add("Value", bindingSource, nameof(SinglePoint.Val), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
bindingSource.DataSource = new[] { new SinglePoint(100) };
[...]
public class SinglePoint : PointList
{
    public SinglePoint(int val) { points.Add(val); }
    public int Val
    {
        get { return points[0]; }
        set
        {
            if (value > 300) value = 300; //(*)
            points[0] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

As a result, when setting for instance a value of 500 on the `NumericUpDown`, after leaving it we should see 300 because of line (*). This works if the base class does not implement `GetHashCode`:

```
public class PointList
{
    protected List<int> points = new List<int>();
    public PointList() { }
    // UNCOMMENT this and the binding will stop working properly
    //public override int GetHashCode()
    //{
    //    unchecked
    //    {
    //        int hashCode = 17;
    //        foreach (var item in points)
    //            hashCode += 13 * item.GetHashCode();

    //        return hashCode;
    //    }
    //}
}
```

However, **if you try to uncomment the `GetHashCode` implementation, the binding will break**. Meaning that after setting 500 and leaving the `NumericUpDown`, the control will still show 500, but in reality the underlying value will be 300. Why is this happening and how could I solve it without turning down my custom implementation of `GetHashCode`?

**EDIT**

As pointed out by some of you, GetHashCode should not change because it is used by the binding mechanism. This reply to the first part of my question. However, how can I make my PointList class satisfying the other [rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/371348/622884) by which "*if two things are equal (Equals(...) == true) then they must return the same value for GetHashCode()*". If I have two `PointList` objects with the same list (sequence) of points I would like them to be found equal (because of other logics in my code), which should imply having the same hash code. How would you do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thumb rule:

> The integer returned by `GetHashCode` **must never change** while the object is contained in a data structure that depends on the hash code remaining stable

See Eric Lippert's article [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/).

In the `GetHashCode` you should use only readonly or immutable fields; otherwise, the object cannot be used in a `Dictionary`, `Hashtable` and other hash-based collections.

Comment: thanks I see now! Can you please check my edits for the second part of my question?

Comment: Conventionally, .NET collections do not return true for `Equals` if they contain the same values. You should let the original `GetHashCode` and `Equals` to reflect reference equality. However, you can implement the `IEnumerable<T>` interface and use the `SequenceEqual` extension method, or you can implement a custom equality check or overload the `==` operator, etc.

Answer (score 4):

WinForms uses the hashcode of the data object and data member to generate a key, which is used to track the data-binded-object in an internal storage. If you change the hash-calculation so that the hash changes when a data member changes value, then previously-generated-key is not updated with it, and is therefor different than the current key. This breaks the data-binding-mechanism.

Source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/BindingContext.cs

Comment: The real answer.

For my use case, I was able to work around this by **not** changing `GetHashCode`  on my domain object (so databinding can know it's working with the right instance). Rather I made a dedicated `DomainObjectEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<DomainObject>` and gave **it** the customized `GetHashCode`. The custom comparer can be passed to Linq functions like `Distinct` so you get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initialising hashcode to 17 you should initialise it with base.GetHashCode().
int hashCode =  base.GetHashCode(); // not 17

Comment: the problem does not change; please check also with your proposed solution