# How to properly override equality logic and preserve data binding capabilities

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, equality, gethashcode

I would like to have a reference on how to correctly implement a class that satisfies following requisites:

1. implementing a logic for equality that depends from its content,
   i.e. its fields
2. proven for data binding

To satisfy point 1, I am used to implement `IEquatable<T>`,to override Object’s `Equals`, `GetHashCode` and `==` and `!=` operators accordingly. Overriding also Object’s `Equals` and `GetHashCode` is important as stated for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13742025/622884) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2009/01/15/if-you-implement-iequatablet-you-still-must-override-objects-equals-and-gethashcode/).

However, `GetHashCode` can return different values according to the fields of the class and I've recently [discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36938219/622884) that for point 2 you need to have `GetHashCode` never changing for a correct data binding in WinForms.

So, it seems I cannot have both the ability to override `==` operator to check for the equality of the class' content and the ability to bind to class properties. Which is the proper way to implement such a class also thinking that other users will access it?

Comment: Make it immutable.